# unable to load photo error is occur when image from a resource folder is try to crop

Tags: android, image, resources, crop

> ```
>    //crop intent of camera
>    Intent cropIntent=new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
>    //get a file from a resource folder
>    File f=new File("android.resource://"+this.getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.i10)+".jpg");
>   Toast.makeText(this,f.getPath(),5).show();
>       f.setWritable(true);
>       f.setExecutable(true);
>       f.setReadable(true);
>        //set data to a Intent
>       cropIntent.setData(Uri.parse(f));
>       cropIntent.setType("image/*");
>       cropIntent.putExtra("crop",true);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
>       cropIntent.putExtra("scale",true);
>       startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
>        //start activity
>        Toast.makeText(this,"croping",5).show();
> ```

'when i will open crop activity it will throw toast message that unable to load image

Comment: there is no demonstration?

Comment: i want to open a res file dynamically because when ever crop Intent is open it will thow toast message because file having no data.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the path to the photo is correct (existing)

If that is OK and you still have the same issue try this.

```
cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(f), "image/*");
```

I experienced some problems too with photo cropping. The setData and setType separately give me an error that my phone does not support cropping (which it does).

If the file exists, create an URI like this.

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/rootexample/example/myfile.jpg"));
```

Comment: no this path is not correct because whenever i check that file is exist of not then it will return false so now question is how can i fetch a file from a resource folder and pass in intent